# How to save data- atributes on widgets (drag/drop)

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor 4.11.3 and I'm developing a drag/drop feature using custom editor.
My goal is to provide replaceable terms for a given document template, e.g. the address of some person.
These info comes from other field in the form, so I need a way to provide some meta info in order to process the document template and make the replacements.
For example: considering my widget as
<span class="h-person">Name</span>
<span class="h-person">Zip Code</span>,
I would like to store on database something like
<span class="h-person" data-bean-model="person.fullName">Name</span>
<span class="h-person" data-bean-model="person.homeAdress.zipCode" data-format-mask="xx.xxx-xxx">Zip Code</span>

I already tried to add the data- properties on dataValue inside paste event, with no success. Even when manually saving the additional info inside the tag that identifies the widget, when data is retrieved and the widged is identified, the data- attributes are lost.
Below follows an example based on https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/draganddrop.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="./ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<style>
    .columns {
        background: #fff;
        color: #000;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    }

    .columns:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }

    .columns>.editor {
        float: left;
        width: 65%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .columns>.contacts {
        float: right;
        width: 35%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    }

    #contactList {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #contactList li {
        background: #FAFAFA;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        height: 56px;
        line-height: 56px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #contactList li:nth-child(2n) {
        background: #F3F3F3;
    }

    #contactList li:hover {
        background: #FFFDE3;
        border-left: 5px solid #DCDAC1;
        margin-left: -5px;
    }

    .contact {
        padding: 0 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }

    .contact .u-photo {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #editor1 .h-card {
        background: #FFFDE3;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    }

    #editor1 {
        border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
        padding: 0 20px;
        background: #fff;
        position: relative;
    }

    #editor1 .h-card .p-tel {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    #editor1 .h-card .p-tel::before,
    #editor1 .h-card .p-tel::after {
        font-style: normal;
    }

    #editor1 .h-card .p-tel::before {
        content: "(☎ ";
    }

    #editor1 .h-card .p-tel::after {
        content: ")";
    }

    #editor1 h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #editor1 hr {
        border-style: dotted;
        border-color: #DCDCDC;
        border-width: 1px 0 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="columns">
    <div class="editor">
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            <h1>The Annual Meeting of Fictional Characters</h1>
            <h3>Technical Announcement</h3>
            <p>We hereby have the pleasure to announce that the theme of this year&apos;s meeting is &quot;<strong>E&#x2013;ink Technology and Classical Fairy Tales</strong>&quot;. As every year, the event will be hosted in <em>The Wonderland</em> by <span class="h-card" data-bean-model="person.homeAdress.zipCode" data-format-mask="xx.xxx-xxx"><a class="p-name u-email" href="mailto:alice@example.com">Alice</a> <span class="p-tel">+20 4345 234 235</span></span> and starts tomorrow at 8:00 GMT.</p>
            <h3>Speakers and Agenda</h3>
            <p>TBA.</p>
            <h3>Venue</h3>
            <p>For detailed information, please contact <span class="h-card" data-something="something1"><a class="p-name u-email" href="mailto:h.finn@example.com">Huckleberry Finn</a> <span class="p-tel">+48 1345 234 235</span></span>.</p>
            <h3>Accommodation</h3>
            <p>Many thanks to <span class="h-card" data-bean-model="person.homeAdress.zipCode" data-format-mask="xx.xxx-xxx"><a class="p-name u-email" href="mailto:r.crusoe@example.com">Robinson Crusoe</a> <span class="p-tel">+45 2345 234 235</span></span> who kindly offered his island to the guests of the annual meeting.</p>
            <hr>
            <p style="text-align: right;"><span class="h-card" data-bean-model="person.homeAdress.zipCode" data-format-mask="xx.xxx-xxx"><a class="p-name u-email" href="mailto:lrrh@example.com">Little Red Riding Hood</a> <span class="p-tel">+45 2345 234 235</span></span></p>
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts">
        <h3>List of Droppable Contacts</h3>
        <ul id="contactList"></ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    'use strict';
    var CONTACTS = [{
        name: 'Huckleberry Finn',
        tel: '+48 1345 234 235',
        email: 'h.finn@example.com',
        avatar: 'hfin',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'D\'Artagnan',
        tel: '+45 2345 234 235',
        email: 'dartagnan@example.com',
        avatar: 'dartagnan',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'Phileas Fogg',
        tel: '+44 3345 234 235',
        email: 'p.fogg@example.com',
        avatar: 'pfog',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'Alice',
        tel: '+20 4345 234 235',
        email: 'alice@example.com',
        avatar: 'alice',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'Little Red Riding Hood',
        tel: '+45 2345 234 235',
        email: 'lrrh@example.com',
        avatar: 'lrrh',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'Winnetou',
        tel: '+44 3345 234 235',
        email: 'winnetou@example.com',
        avatar: 'winetou',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'Edmond Dantès',
        tel: '+20 4345 234 235',
        email: 'count@example.com',
        avatar: 'edantes',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    },
    {
        name: 'Robinson Crusoe',
        tel: '+45 2345 234 235',
        email: 'r.crusoe@example.com',
        avatar: 'rcrusoe',
        beanModel : 'person.homeAdress.zipCode',
        formatMask : 'xx.xxx-xxx'
    }
    ];

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('hcard', {
        requires: 'widget',

        init: function(editor) {
            editor.widgets.add('hcard', {
                allowedContent: 'span(!h-card); a[href](!u-email,!p-name); span(!p-tel)',
                requiredContent: 'span(h-card)',
                pathName: 'hcard',

                upcast: function(el) {
                    return el.name == 'span' && el.hasClass('h-card');
                }
            });

            editor.addFeature(editor.widgets.registered.hcard);

            editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
                var contact = evt.data.dataTransfer.getData('contact');

                if (!contact) {
                    return;
                }

                evt.data.dataValue =
                    '<span class="h-card" data-bean-model="' + contact.beanModel + ' data-format-mask="' + contact.formatMask + '">' +
                    '<a href="mailto:' + contact.email + '" class="p-name u-email">' + contact.name + '</a>' +
                    ' ' +
                    '<span class="p-tel">' + contact.tel + '</span>' +
                    '</span>';
            });
        }
    });

    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function() {
        CKEDITOR.document.getById('contactList').on('dragstart', function(evt) {
            var target = evt.data.getTarget().getAscendant('div', true);

            CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.initDragDataTransfer(evt);

            var dataTransfer = evt.data.dataTransfer;

            dataTransfer.setData('contact', CONTACTS[target.data('contact')]);
            dataTransfer.setData('text/html', target.getText());

            if (dataTransfer.$.setDragImage) {
                dataTransfer.$.setDragImage(target.findOne('img').$, 0, 0);
            }
        });
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        extraPlugins: 'hcard,sourcedialog,justify,format'
        , height: 400
    });
</script>

<script>
    'use strict';

    addItems(
        CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'contactList' ),
            new CKEDITOR.template(
                '<div class="contact h-card" data-contact="{id}" data-bean-model="{beanModel}" data-format-mask="{formatMask}">' +
                '<img src="assets/draganddrop/img/{avatar}.png" alt="avatar" class="u-photo" /> {name}' +
                '</div>'
            ),
        CONTACTS
    );

    function addItems( listElement, template, items ) {
        for ( var i = 0, draggable, item; i < items.length; i++ ) {
            item = new CKEDITOR.dom.element( 'li' );

            draggable = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(
                template.output( {
                    id: i,
                    name: items[ i ].name,
                    avatar: items[ i ].avatar,
                    beanModel: items[ i ].beanModel,
                    formatMask: items[ i ].formatMask
                } )
            );

            draggable.setAttributes( {
                draggable: 'true',
                tabindex: '0'
            } );

            item.append( draggable );
            listElement.append( item );
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It need these extra info to be stored on database in order to be able to perform the replacements again when retrieving this from database later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

Inside `init` function, added the rule `[data-*]` for attributes on allowedContent

```
editor.widgets.add('hcard', {
    allowedContent: 'span(!h-card)[data-*]; a[href](!u-email,!p-name); span(!p-tel)',
    requiredContent: 'span(h-card)',
    pathName: 'hcard',
```

See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules.html